# Select Count (distinct col) query to show number of rows and column in result - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table with few columns, col1, col2, col3, col4. I want to count how much rows of unique values are in col3. The results needs to be showing number of rows and values too. How do I form such a query. I am using PgAdmin4.

```
col1. col2.  col3.   col4.
  x1   y1     123   xx-xx-xxxx   
  x2   y2     123   xx-xx-xxxx
  x3   y3     123   xx-xx-xxxx
  x4   y4     111   xx-xx-xxxx
  x5   y5     111   xx-xx-xxxx
```

I tried using `select count( distinct col3) from table_ where col3_ts >'2019-09-17'`
But it counts/shows number of all distinct rows only i.e. a number only like 8999.

The example results are like:

```
    #.  col3.    # of rows.
   -----------------------
    1.  123        3 
    2.  111        2
   -----------------------
```

Comment: please share some examples.

Comment: @jjanes: I tried to add example. I hope it will help.

Comment: you don't need distinct count, you just need group by count().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic GROUP BY use case:

```
select col3, count(*) from table_ where col3_ts >'2019-09-17' GROUP BY col3.
```